# Circle is appearing as 2 separate circles rather than circle with a fill. How can I merge them and add a fill?

Tags: modeling

I'm looking to combine 2 paths to make 1 circle that can have a fill. I would appreciate any help. i have searched online and tried all the suggestions but it won't work. I'm also trying to add a black background but the fill is priority. I may be able to add the black background in photoshop if not possible.

[image]

Comment: hi Niall try to select both curve objects and join them -Ctrl+J- that should make a compound path... may need to change fill mode later -in Object Data properties panel-

Comment: (..... and the curves must be 2D to work that way)